# Getting "Error: could not parse function arguments ()=>"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Following is my code :-

```
projectDependencies.forEach((val)=>
{
    container.register(val[0],function ()
    {
        return require(val[1]);
    });
});
```

While I run the command, nodemon server.js I am getting the below error:

```
Error: could not parse function arguments: ()=>
{
    return container;
}
    at argList (C:\Users\Data-Vinci\Desktop\JS\chatapp\node_modules\dependable\index.js:97:15)
    at toFactory (C:\Users\Data-Vinci\Desktop\JS\chatapp\node_modules\dependable\index.js:82:21)
    at registerOne (C:\Users\Data-Vinci\Desktop\JS\chatapp\node_modules\dependable\index.js:33:32)
    at Object.register (C:\Users\Data-Vinci\Desktop\JS\chatapp\node_modules\dependable\index.js:26:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Data-Vinci\Desktop\JS\chatapp\container.js:22:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

I think my code is syntactically correct. Can't figure where the problem is.

Note:- However if I use function() instead of ()=> then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

dependable.argList converts the function to a string and parses out the arg names. The arrow function doesn't stringify to what it is looking for.

https://github.com/Schoonology/dependable/blob/master/index.coffee#L63

```
match = func.toString().match /function.*?\(([\s\S]*?)\)/
if not match? then throw new Error "could not parse function arguments: #{func?.toString()}"
```

eg

```
> func = function(val){ console.log(val); }
> func.toString()
'function (val){ console.log(val); }'

> arrowFunc = (val) => console.log(val);
> arrowFunc.toString();
'(val) => console.log(val)'
```